# Moving branch to a fork

Tags: github

We have a lot of branches in one of our deployment repos. I've found several of them are works in progress that just got pushed to the back burner.

I'm trying to find a way of getting the paused project branches off the repo, but still retain them. I had an idea of forking the repo, but I'm not sure how I would move the branch from the main repo to the fork.

Is this something that's doable, other than re-creating the branch from scratch and moving the files into it?

I'm also open to suggestions on better ways if there are some.